# Load bootstrap modal from seperate page on button click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a web-page `default.html` containing button with `id ="btn-add"` and another page `add-students.html` containing only bootstrap modal. How can I load modal in `default.html` on clicking a button (`btn-add`).

Code for Button :

```
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-add" style="float:right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"><strong> Add</strong></span>
```

First one loads table automatically on page load from next page. I did similarly for modal but didn't work.

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
            //load student table automatically
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/grid/grid-students.html",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#data").html(result);
                    }                     

                });
           //load modal 
                $("btn-add").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax/add/add-students.html", success: function (result) {
                            $(document).load(result);
                        }
                    });
                });



       });
```

my modal code in add-students:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Applicants</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form role="form">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
                    </div><br />
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
                    </div><br />
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
                    </div><br />
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
                    </div>


                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make 2 ajax requests when you nest `load()` inside success of `$.ajax`

You can do this using `$.get()` which is a shorthand method for `$.ajax` and then in the completion callback opening the modal.

I would remove the data attributes from the button first since bootstrap will be unable to find the target since it doesn't exist.

```
// note invalid selector for button in your code
$("#btn-add").click(function () {
    // get needed html
    $.get("ajax/add/add-students.html", function (result) {
        // append response to body
        $('body').append(result);
        // open modal
        $('#myModal2').modal(/* options object here*/);

    });
});
```

You might also want to check for existence of the modal element before loading it's html each time since ID's must be unique

You can check using something like:

```
if(!$('#myModal2').length){
  // load html and open new modal
}else{
   // just open modal...see docs
}
```